# Previous view cutting off at top after view on top is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main view and two sub views that load whenever the corresponding "Read More" button is pressed.

Both these buttons are programmed the same except that they load different views and pass different data (although the layout and functionality of both are the same).

When the first button is pressed everything remains normal by having the new view appear on top and I can click close to get rid of it.

When the second button is pressed the top view appears and can be closed but the original view somehow moves up and gets cut off.

It's a little hard to explain so I created a quick video to show you what is happening:
http://screencast.com/t/Yyy8J1BSnj

As you can see I can click the first button, launch the new view, close it and everything remains the same.  When I click the second button the new view launches and I can close it but then the original view moves.

Any idea what is causing this?

This is the code that launches the two views:

```
- (IBAction)readMoreBackground:(id)sender {
NRMReadMoreBackgroundViewController *readMoreBackgroundController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"readMoreBackgroundID"];

// Passing background text to the backgroundFullText variable for use on next view
readMoreBackgroundController.backgroundFullText = self.backgroundText.text;

[self presentViewController:readMoreBackgroundController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }

- (IBAction)readMoreInscription:(id)sender {
NRMReadMoreInscriptionViewController *readMoreInscriptionController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"readMoreInscriptionID"];

// Passing inscription text to the inscriptionTextFull variable for use on next view
readMoreInscriptionController.inscriptionTextFull = self.inscription.text;

[self presentViewController:readMoreInscriptionController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and this is the code that closes the views when the close button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)closereadMoreBackgroundView:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)closeReadMoreInscriptionView:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have the same issue...